# CNUI ERROR Selection predicates are set but the delegate does not implement contactPicker:didSelectContact:

Tags: objective-c, contacts, ios9

I try to use the new iOS 9.0 **CNContactPickerViewController** to select a contact in objective-C. I set the delegate and implement the **CNContactPickerDelegate** methods.

```
@import ContactsUI;
@import Contacts;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void) presentContacts
{
    CNContactPickerViewController *contactPicker = [[CNContactPickerViewController alloc] init];
    contactPicker.delegate = self;
    contactPicker.predicateForEnablingContact = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"familyName LIKE[cd] 'smith'"];
    contactPicker.predicateForSelectionOfContact = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TRUEPREDICATE"];
    [_myViewController presentViewController:contactPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void) contactPickerDidCancel: (CNContactPickerViewController *) picker
{
    NSLog(@"didCancel");
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void) contactPicker: (CNContactPickerViewController *) picker
      didSelectContact: (CNContact *)                     contact
{
    NSLog(@"didSelectContact"):
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)      contactPicker: (CNContactPickerViewController *) picker
   didSelectContactProperty: (CNContactProperty *)             contactProperty
{
    NSLog(@"didSelectProperty");
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The contacts picker is presented with 'smith' selectable but I get the following message:

**[CNUI ERROR] Selection predicates are set but the delegate does not implement contactPicker:didSelectContact: and contactPicker:didSelectContactProperty:. Those predicates will be ignored.**

And I never get any log from the delegate methods. It behaves exactly as the line

```
    contactPicker.delegate = self;
```

is ignored. Even I click on the "cancel" button in the picker, I don't get my "didCancel" message but I get another message:

**plugin com.apple.MobileAddressBook.ContactsViewService invalidated**

I found in https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12275 somebody with the similar problem in swift and he solved it telling us: *"So I found that the ContactsPicker I was calling was in the wrong module"* but I do not understand how we can get the wrong module and how to call the "right" module.

I have the same problem on the simulator and on a real device (iPad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Joel in my related question [With CNContactPickerViewController in iOS 9.0, how to enable/disable single or multiple selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815260/with-cncontactpickerviewcontroller-in-ios-9-0-how-to-enable-disable-single-or-m/32851696#32851696), I found that I just forgot to store the CNContactPickerViewController in a *property* that exists the time the user make the selection.

So my code becomes:

```
- (void) presentContacts
{
    _contactPicker = [[CNContactPickerViewController alloc] init];
    contactPicker.delegate = self;
    ...
}
```