# With CNContactPickerViewController in iOS 9.0, how to enable/disable single or multiple selection?

Tags: contacts, ios9

The delegate CNContactPickerDelegate have methods for single and multiple selections. But how do we specify we want single or multiple selection when we present the view controller?

I guess I miss something that perhaps also causes the problem I have described in: [CNUI ERROR Selection predicates are set but the delegate does not implement contactPicker:didSelectContact:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802087/cnui-error-selection-predicates-are-set-but-the-delegate-does-not-implement-cont)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to implement ONLY the method you need.

If you want only one contact, implement:

> contactPicker:didSelectContact:

If you want multiple selection, implement:

> contactPicker:didSelectContacts:

If you want select one property for one contact, implemente:

> contactPicker:didSelectContactProperty:

And the last one, don't know how work, looks like a bug, because if I implement it, I get the multiple contact selection UI, but can't select properties.

> contactPicker:didSelectContactProperties:

EDIT:
Finally I got some data from didSelectContactProperties, this method required a definition in predicateForSelectionOfProperty. I think the name is incorrect, should be didSelectContactsProperties, because I got the properties for multiple contacts.

Comment: I tried that in objective-c but I never got any selection... and this design is not the best.
BTW did you try in objective-c or swift?

Comment: Only swift, I forgot everything about obj-c last year ;)

Comment: did you try using a global variable for  CNContactPicker ?

Comment: YES !!! I forgot to save the picker as a global variable. Stupid me! And this also solved my related problem!

Comment: I want to enable or disable multiple contact selection based on condition in same controller how I can do that?

Comment: @PradumnaPatil maybe having two different delegates and changing them based on the condition ? I'm sorry this answer is old, I don't remember well how it works.

Comment: I've always used "self" as the delegate, but now I want to have two buttons in a VC that use `CNContactPickerViewController` with different selection modes,, so I assume that I should make a separate class for each version of the delegate?

Comment: @benc I would check the parameters received by the delegate method. You might get useful information to identify who triggered the call.

Comment: Just a note to `didSelectContactProperties` - the predicate must specify one and only one contact property key, otherwise empty array is returned. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283894/select-multiple-properties-from-single-contact-in-cncontactpicker/50284947#50284947