# select multiple properties from single contact in CNContactPicker

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact, cncontactviewcontroller, cncontactpicker

I am trying to use the CNContactPickerViewController and keep running into issues with how to **pick multiple properties from a single contact**

Basic display of the picker

```
    let contactStore = CNContactStore()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.askForContactAccess()
    self.displayContacts()
}

func displayContacts(){
    let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
    contactPicker.delegate = self
    self.present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

this displays the address book after the user gives permission(the code is there but didn't show it above)

Now what I would like to do is when the user selects a contact we navigate into the contact details view(this happens currently) but when I try to use the delegate

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContactProperties contactProperties: [CNContactProperty])
```

I get presented with the contact picker view where I can select multiple contacts. I don't mind trying to extend the contact detail view so that I can select multiple properties but I don't even know how to hook into it.

I can create a completely **custom table view** and select the properties there but since apple created a nice contact detail view I would rather use that.

Comment: I think you need to seed the [`CNContactPickerViewController#displayedPropertyKeys`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contactsui/cncontactpickerviewcontroller/1619203-displayedpropertykeys) with the properties you want to be displayed before the picker will display the property sheet for a specific contact

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer  - I'm not sure about the propertykeys since I really do want it to display all properties in the contact.  Right now when I don't add a delegate function it does display the whole details card..I just can't do anything with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** - No, you can't use `CNContactPickerViewController` to select multiple properties from one contact.

**Full version:**

`CNContactPickerViewController` is poorly and confusingly implemented.

It in fact does not actually support the ability to select multiple properties from a single contact. The picker is automatically dismissed after selecting a single contact property.

It does not actually let the user select specific properties from multiple contacts.

It supports the following:

- Select a single contact
- Select a single property of a single contact
- Select multiple contacts
- Select multiple contacts and return a single predetermined (not user chosen) property from each of the user selected multiple contacts.

To get the `didSelectContactProperties` delegate to be called with anything other than an empty list of properties, you must set the `predicateForSelectionOfProperty` property to a predicate that specifies one and only one contact property key. If you provide any other predicate, the get a black screen when you tap on a contact and your app is now hung and needs to be killed.

I believe there are several bugs associated with picking contact properties of multiple contacts.

**Workaround:**

I believe the only solution (besides your own complete custom view controllers around the Contacts framework) would be to make your own multiple property selection by combining `CNContactPickerViewController` in single contact selection mode, followed by using `CNContactViewController` to display the details of the selected contact. Then implement the `contactViewController(_:shouldPerformDefaultActionFor:)` delegate method to keep track of the properties chosen by the user.

Comment: Thank you Maddy for a very thorough explanation.  I agree it looks like picker seems to be poorly implemented.  I did find that by implementing `contactPicker.predicateForSelectionOfContact = NSPredicate(value: false)` and then using the `func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contactProperty: CNContactProperty)` I could at least click on multiple properties and add them to my array of properties, but I don't see a way to keep the highlight/place a checkbox next to each of the properties since I have no way of actually getting access to the detail viewcontroller

Comment: Maddy in terms of your workaround...even if I keep it in single contact selection mode when I click a contact it either dismissed the view immediately(if `predicateForSelectionOfContact = NSPredicate(value: true)` or takes me to the detail view if the predicate is set to false.  Do you know of a clean way to actually display the cncontactviewcontroller?

Comment: I haven't actually tried my suggested possible workaround. But I would guess you would have to display the `CNContactViewController` after the `CNContactPickerViewController` is dismissed.