# Extend or subclass CNContactViewController to multi-select with checks

Tags: swift, cncontact, cncontactviewcontroller, cncontactpicker

I would like to be able pull up a CNContactViewController with a single contact. Within this page I want to add the functionality of multi-select so I can choose muttiple properties and as the user selects each property either highlight or place a check next to each.

1. Would extending the CNContactViewController or subclassing it be better? - my assumption is subclassing since this is going to be a specific use case and I don't need to extend all CNContactViewControllers in the app
2. how would I go about adding the checkmark/highlighting functionality?
3. I can present the view controller currently but I'm not even sure if its a tableview or a containerview right now.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Neither approach will work. `CNContactViewController` is not something you can modify like you want. You would need to write your own custom class that displays the properties of a `CNContact`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283894/select-multiple-properties-from-single-contact-in-cncontactpicker

Comment: Thank you Maddy.  I wrote that original question as well. I was trying to see how I can now pick from multiple properties within the contactviewcontroller itself like you recommended.  Not really looking forward to re-writing the whole contact view.