# CNContactViewController.highlightProperty(withKey:identifier:) not highlighting

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cncontactviewcontroller

CNContactViewController.highlightProperty(withKey:identifier:) isn't highlighting the property like it's supposed to.

I'm getting error message in debug window:

> [PPT] Error creating the CFMessagePort needed to communicate with PPT.

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix this?

I am using Xcode 14.3 and an iPhone 8 device with iOS 16.4.1 (a).

[image]

Code:

```
print("self.contact.emailAddresses.first!.identifier):\n\t\(String(describing: self.contact.emailAddresses.first!.identifier))")
self.contactViewController.highlightProperty(withKey: CNContactEmailAddressesKey, identifier: self.contact.emailAddresses.first!.identifier)
```

More in debug window:

```
self.contact.emailAddresses.first!.identifier):
    ED15C6E7-0E63-4E0F-A868-6E450D6E7FDF
2023-05-29 11:46:45.742750-0500 TrialCNContactViewContollerInits[4726:216791] [Graphics] UIColor created with component values far outside the expected range. Set a breakpoint on UIColorBreakForOutOfRangeColorComponents to debug. This message will only be logged once.
2023-05-29 11:46:46.305697-0500 TrialCNContactViewContollerInits[4726:216791] [PPT] Error creating the CFMessagePort needed to communicate with PPT.
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same error on an iPhone 13 running iOS 16.6. Perhaps the first error about UIColor is more relevant to the issue. Could be an iOS bug.

Comment: it is feasible for you to put your code in test new project and share it with us to check and fix that issue and revert it to you ?? @daniel

Comment: @Chandaboy Yes. I'll do that.

Comment: @Chandaboy I started a new Xcode project to test my code. It still doesn't work. I created a repository of the project on GitHub. Here's the url to the project: https://github.com/Shinehah-Gnolaum/TestHighlightContactProperties.git

Comment: @daniel I have tried to fix hightilght issue and do some research and found it out that its not possible as its apple lib and don't have permission to do it please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52453229/extend-or-subclass-cncontactviewcontroller-to-multi-select-with-checks

Comment: @Chandaboy I haven't been able to figure it out either. At one time there was a bug report sent to Apple according to Apple Developer Forums.